# Algorithm for ConnectAll game

Tags: algorithm, game-physics

here is the video of game I am interested in.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhWeLmSf6pA

I would like to know the algorithm that is used to make a pattern for challenge as shown in video.

Can anyone tell me, which algorithm i should use to make a clone of this game in windows.

Thanks

Comment: Simply sort out all possible positions of four marks, solve each one by brute-forcing, and select for challenge only those positions that have unique solution.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. but I think, brute-forcing is not good solution.. still looking for some better solution.

Comment: Brute-forcing on 16-cell field is very fast  ;-)

Comment: Without going into too much detail, I'd probably generate a random path that covers the graph and assign `2` and `3` to random positions in this path with `1` being first and `4` being last in the path. Determining the difficulty of a given level could be a little difficult.

Comment: @Dukeling thats nice thought.. make sense and probably i have something to start implement.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a Hamiltonian path problem. If someone can find a general solution better than bruteforce, I would be interested.

The board can be translated to a graph. Every piece is a node, the connections are edges. There are many graph packages and algorithms to find a Hamiltonian path. You can easily create your own model and recursive or iterative solution.

The upper bound for the number of solution search can be guesses: We have 4 nodes with 2 edges, makes only 1 choice and a factor of 1^2. 8 nodes with 3 edges, makes 2 choices and a factor of 2^8. And 4 nodes with 4 edges, makes 3 choices and a factor of 3^4. The starting point has one option more, makes a factor of 2. For sure, we have 16 different starting points. In total, the upper bound would be 1^2*2^8*3^4*2*16 = 663.552. The set of solutions would be smaller, because we will have dead ends.

For this specific problem, we can even reduce it a little bit more, because we need only three starting points, (0,0), (0,1) and (1,1). If we have all solutions for this three points, we can use a function to generate mirrored and rotated solutions. Makes an upper bound of 124.416.

After we have all solutions, we can place the 2 and 3 points somewhere in between each solution. We can even create a function to guess the "hardness" of a solution by counting all possibilities to have the 2 and 3 at the same node and same place.

If we just want to create different puzzles, a backtracking with random directions would be totally fine. Easy to implement and fast running time should be expected.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Do you know of any library or formula for Hamilton path algorithm..?